# Handling external media in C#/Mono on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono

What I'm wanting to do is detect if an external memory stick is present in a Raspberry-Pi USB socket and then try to read or write files to it. The reading or writing is straightforward (StreamReader etc)  but the actual path isn't clear.

On Windows it'd be D:, E: etc. I've looked a lot but information about handling external devices in code seems hard to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives` which return `DriveInfo[]`

DriveInfo also has a DriveType property of type enum that might come in useful:

> CDRom 5    The drive is an optical disc device, such as a CD or DVD-ROM.
>
> Fixed 3    The drive is a fixed disk.
>
> Network   4    The drive is a network drive.
>
> NoRootDirectory   1    The drive does not have a root directory.
>
> Ram   6    The drive is a RAM disk.
>
> Removable 2    The drive is a removable storage device, such as a USB
>   flash drive.
>
> Unknown   0    The type of drive is unknown.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I needed. Curiously, it found the same drive twice in the list; easy to filter out though. and reported it as Type fixed rather than removeable. I was easily able to read a text file I'd placed on it. Thanks once again!